# returning values in a applet?

Tags: java, applet

Anyone know how I can go about doing this inside a action listener? I have the following

```
private void (java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                   
    if (studentComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Student 1")){


jlabel1=return parameter ="i"



String i = getParameter("student2");
```

But im sure return parameter is not correct

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Plus you are not using correct capitalization.

Comment: Your code and question still don't make sense.  What are the last three lines?  Are you trying to retrieve 3 parameters or 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when the user selects a different value in the `studentComboBox`, you want the `jlabel1` to change its text? If so, this should do it:

```
String h = getParameter("student1");
String i = getParameter("student2");
String j = getParameter("student3");

private void studentComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                   
    if (studentComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Student 1")){
        jlabel1.setText(h);
    } else if (studentComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Student 2")){
        jlabel1.setText(i);
    } else if (studentComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Student 3")){
        jlabel1.setText(j);
    }
}
```

Notice that `studentComboBoxItemStateChanged` does not need to return anything. You just simply call methods on the `jlabel1` object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Return allows you to specify a value to return. It doesn't allow you to do an assignment; it's up to the code that called your method to determine how to act.

In any case, your method `studentComboBoxItemStateChanged` is a `void` method which means it can't return a value (regular `return` works, it just leaves the method).

It's up to you and what you need. The best solution in your case is probably to set some variable or call some function with a parameter in each of the `if`s.

**EDIT** If you're trying to set the value of jlabel1 to `"h"`, `"i"`, `"j"`

```
if (studentComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Student 1")) { jlabel1.setValue("h"); }
....
```

But it looks like you're trying to use the *variables* `h`, `i`, and `j`. Remember that `"h"` is different than `h`.

```
if (studentComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Student 1")) { jlabel1.setValue(h); }
....
```

But to do that, `h`, `i`, and `j` will need to be defined as instance variables, outside of the method.

The *best* solution in this case, assuming the label should hold the value of getParameter("student1"), is to do just that:

```
if (studentComboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Student 1")) { jlabel1.setValue(getParameter("student1")); }
....
```

As somebody else mentioned, a map would be very well-suited for this

```
Map<String, String> prettyNamesToParameterNames= ...;

private void StudentComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    String paramName=prettyNamestoParameterNames.get(studentComboBox.getSelectedItem());
    label1.setValue(getParameter(paramName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to set a variable based on a selected item in a JComboBox.  To do that your syntax is wrong, you don't need to use the return keyword, just set the variable you want.

If you need to return a value, then just return the value you want to return and change your method signature to specify your return type.

Lastly, instead of using a set of messy if/else statements use a Map.  It will be much clearer, much more efficient and much easier to change later.  Also, does your code account for null being selected.